# Use Microsoft Graph to reset user password *and* send password to specified email address

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm able to use the Microsoft Graph API to reset a user password by updating the `passwordProfile` property on the `User`. However, I can't figure out how to duplicate the functionality that existes in the Microsoft Office Portal that allows me to send that password to a specified email address. See this screenshot.

[image: Final password reset step in MOP showing option to send password in email]

Is there a way to do this through any Microsoft API or PowerShell commands?

Comment: Microsoft Graph does have an operation to send email. What else do you need here?

Comment: I want Microsoft to send the email about the new password like it does when clicking the button in the screenshot.